# Fetching only one field using sorm framework

Tags: scala, sorm

Is it possible to fetch only one field from the database using the [SORM Framework](http://sorm-framework.org/)?

What I want in plain SQL would be:

```
SELECT node_id FROM messages
```

I can't seem to be able to reproduce this in sorm. I know this might be against how sorm is supposed to work, but right now I have two huge tables with different kind of messages. I was asked to get all the unique `node_id`s from both tables.

I know I could just query both tables using sorm and parse through all the data but I would like to put the database to work. Obviously, this would be even better if one can get only unique `node_id`s in a single db call.

Right now with just querying everything and parsing it, it takes way too long.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be ORM support for what you want to do, unless `node_id` happens to be the primary key of your `Message` object:

```
val messages = Db.query[Message].fetchIds()
```

In this case you shouldn't need to worry about it being `UNIQUE`, since primary keys are by definition unique. Alternatively, you can run a custom SQL query:

```
Db.fetchWithSql[Message]("SELECT DISTINCT node_id FROM messages")
```

Note this latter might be typed wrong: you'd have to try it against your database. You might need `fetchWithSql[Int]`, or some other variation: it is unclear what SORM does in the eventuality that the primary key hasn't been queried.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the help. Unfortunately node_id is not unique or an primary id of any table. Also I think that SORM's `fetchWithSql` limitation is that it can only query id columns. I tried it and it gives me the `assertion failed: The sql-statement must select only the id-column`

Comment: @MikeJones Ah, then you might be out of luck. SORM seems like a very undeveloped framework at this juncture, lacking a lot of things you'd think were obvious, sadly. I really can't find anything in their source that suggests this is possible, besides the `fetchWithSql`.